# How to insert into two tables that are both related together with foreign_keys?

Tags: python, database, sqlite, server-side

Here are my tables :

```
CREATE TABLE thread
(
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    title TEXT,
    post_id INTEGER,
    FOREIGN KEY(post_id) REFERENCES post(id)
);

CREATE TABLE post
(
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    message TEXT,
    thread_id INTEGER,
    user_id INTEGER,
    FOREIGN KEY(thread_id) REFERENCES thread(id),
    FOREIGN KEY(user_id) REFERENCES user(id)
);
```

I have a thread table that contain the id of the first post (the author's post).

If I want to insert a new post in an existing thread, it's easy because I know the `thread_id`.

But if I want to create a new thread, I need to know the `post_id` of the post that does not exist yet.

At the moment I do it with multiples SQL queries and multiples commits :

```
cur = db.execute("""
      INSERT INTO post (content, user_id)
      VALUES(?, ?, ?)""", [content, user_id])
db.commit()
post_id = cur.lastrowid
cur = db.execute("""
      INSERT INTO thread (title, post_id)
      VALUES(?, ?, ?)""", [title, post_id])
db.commit()
thread_id = cur.lastrowid
db.execute("""
      UPDATE post
      SET thread_id = ?
      WHERE id=?""", [thread_id, post_id])
db.commit()
```

But it's very ugly and i think there is a better solution.
If I could do something like this, it would be perfect, but it's not allowed :

```
INSERT INTO thread(title)
    VALUES("thread 1");
INSERT INTO post(post, thread_id)
    VALUES("first post of thread 1", LAST_INSERT_ROWID() AS tmp);
UPDATE thread
    SET post_id = LAST_INSERT_ROWID()
    WHERE id = tmp;
```

Any ideas ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to (and should not) call `commit()` between your statements.

Reading `lastrowid` is the correct way to get the autoincrement ID of the inserted row.

---

Storing the first post's ID is not necessary because it can be derived from other information:

```sql
SELECT id FROM post WHERE thread_id = ? ORDER BY /* timestamp */ id LIMIT 1;
```

Storing it would make sense only as an optimization, but nothing in your question indicates that this would be necessary.